# Make a timeline from year and day numbers

Tags: matlab, timeline

I want to make a timeline.

The below code extracts information from columns A and B of some Excel workbooks. In Column A are years, column B contains the day number (for that year) when an event happened.

My question is: How can I plot this with Station1, Station2 ect. on the Y-axis, and year on X-axis? I want the graph to make a point on the day (and the right year) where my Excel sheet has data.

```
num = xlsread('station1.xlsx', 1, 'A:B');
num3 = xlsread('station2.xlsx', 1, 'A:B');
num4 = xlsread('station3.xlsx', 1, 'A:B');
num5 = xlsread('station5.xlsx', 1, 'A:B');
```

Example data:

```
num =  2000      193
       2000      199
       2000      220
       2000      228
       2000      241
       2000      244
       2000      250
       2000      257        
       2016      287
       2016      292
       2016      294
       2016      300
```

Comment: We have no idea what the data looks like in your Excel files...

Comment: I understand. My excel have four columns with data, but I only need the two first. I have managed to extract the data(The two first columns) that I need as shown in my script. I only need help to plot this as explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `datetime` and `caldays` to convert your year / day of year data into actual dates:

```
dnum = datetime(num(:,1),1,1) + caldays(num(:,2));
% dnum = '12-Jul-2000'
%        '18-Jul-2000'
%        '08-Aug-2000' 
%        ...
```

Plot a line with marks on every date:

```
hold on % to plot multiple lines
plot(dnum, 1*ones(size(dnum)), 'x-')    % Change the 1 to the y-axis value
plot(dnum2, 2*ones(size(dnum2)), 'x-')  % Line at y=2 with other dates dnum2
hold off
```

Output (zoomed in on x-axis to show year 2000 dates):

[image: timelines]

---

If your files are named as in your example, then you can replace your whole code with a loop to avoid declaring loads of `num` variables and calling `plot` over many lines:

```
figure; hold on;
for ii = 1:5
    num = xlsread(['station', num2str(ii), '.xlsx'], 1, 'A:B');
    dnum = datetime(num(:,1),1,1) + caldays(num(:,2));
    plot(dnum, 1*ones(size(dnum)), 'x-');
end
hold off
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No worries Kathy :)